# Android phone taps touchscreen on its own

Tags: hardware, touchscreen

I have an LG P690 Optimus Net. The issue I am having is that the phone often enters a state where it keeps on pressing the touchscreen's buttons by its self, and I have to press the back button several times to try and go back while it keeps opening new screens or entering text on its own.

I was wondering, is this something anyone else has experienced? How common is this defect, and has it to do with Optimus Net phones or with phones in general? Are some line of products more susceptible than others? If common then how does the problem I just described typically arise? Could accidentally dropping the phone or humidity in the air cause it for instance?

Comment: Have you tried removing the battery for 30-60 seconds?

Did you kill the facebook app once. As in https://community.verizonwireless.com/thread/768059

If this still does not solve your problem, please do let us know...

Comment: Seems to be a current epidemy -- this is already the 3rd such question I see within 3 days. Related: [HTC Hero touch screen don't work correctly](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42918/16575), [screen keeps jerking and there are automatic touches](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/42904/16575)

Answer (score 3):

> I have no Article to show, I have not cross checked on Internet.
>   Below is my personal doing.

Phone screen taps on its own. This usually happens to me when the phone is charging and I try to use it.

### There could be some possible causes which I suspect:

- Phone screen might not be clean. Sweat, dirt, food particles from hand can cause pseudo taps.
- When charging or after charging, static electricity on the phone surface might also be the cause.

### How I fixed it?

- Get a clean cotton cloth
- Rub it steadily on the screen to remove any particles causing taps.
- For static current removal, just remove the battery from phone and press the `Power` button for 10 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Seems there is a problem. The touchscreen takes inputs that was never made. Have a look at this http://www.thinkdigit.com/forum/mobiles-tablets/122921-official-android-discussion-thread-73.html#post1836923

There are various problems of Android that LG ships on the P690. I'd suggest installing a good custom ROM, which should fix the problem if it is not a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the touch-screen of LG p690. I've installed a new custom ROM and searched a lot for answers.

In my experience, it's a hardware issue causing the touch-screen to randomly press itself.

My solution? I have a new phone.