# Strange Issue(Auto Touch) with Touch on HTC Desire X. Has anyone experienced this?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, factory-reset, touchscreen, htc-desire-x

I have got a HTC Desire X about 3 months ago. I've quite enjoyed the features it comes with. For the past week or so, I have been facing with this strange issue. The touch screen acts as if it is being touched even when I am not touching the screen.

First, I couldn't understand what was happening as calls were getting disconnected or answered automatically. Then, I turned the Show visual Feedback for touches from the developer options in settings. I could now clearly see the screen is detecting a touch on its own.

I Factory resetted the device from the settings and from Bootloader as well. It works fine for a couple of days without any issues. But, the issue comes back.

Please help me with this issues.

Thanks in advance.

TLDR: Touchscreen touches automatically. Factory reset resolves the issue, but only for some time(2 days at max, an hour at min).

Comment: You might want to check [Android phone taps touchscreen on its own](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/43001/16575), the problem sounds quite similar :)

Comment: I think this may be a design flaw in the hardware. My friend has an HTC one with the same problem. He can temporarily alleviate the problem by twisting the top and bottom of the phone in opposite directions. Be careful not to damage the handset though, as I'd recommend getting it swapped on warranty.

Comment: I had this problem on my HTC Desire X, the phone would auto-answer calls as well. Took it to a service center, and they replaced the touch screen altogether. This is common in Desire X it seems, which makes this a poor manufacturing defect

Comment: I too had taken it to the service center, and they replaced the Touch Screen as well. I agree with you on the manufacturing defect.